# firefox can be fingerprinted

Tags: security

https://www.browserleaks.com/firefox

it can be used for both fingerprinting (different users use different OS setups or different Tor versions) and exploiting software vulnerabilities because when attacker don’t know your OS or browser version they don’t know what payload can do the thing that if be used incorrectly will show a download warning that compromises their valuable malware to citizenlab like groups.

Comment: why Tor developers don't disable that thing in the TBB?

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: Also worth noting that it's possible to write polyglot payloads that work across architectures and operating systems, so even if the attacker doesn't know the platform they can construct some shellcode that will allow them to execute their chosen payload, blindly. As such this isn't actually a useful protection against exploitation and your claims on that basis are clearly made from a position of ignorance. It is however a fingerprinting problem that splits anonymity sets. Pretend it stops exploitation however, is purely deluding yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Not everything is a simple flip of a switch or a change of an option.

It's being worked on with progressions on both Tor project and Mozilla.
Tor ticket: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/8725.
Related Mozilla bug ticket: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=863246

By the way, the https://www.browserleaks.com/whois information doesn't matter. That's all about your exit.

Relax.

Comment: Worth noting that the 6.5 series (currently alpha) already has this patch and defeats this fingerprinting method. It's a non-trivial patch.